# what does means Paper status: Finished?

Tags: publications, peer-review, journals, paper-submission, review-articles

I submitted my paper to a journal. After 6 mounth with status: under review, yesterday the status changed to "paper status: Finished". I don't understand what does means by this?

Comment: I would assume that "finished" means the reviews are complete and ready for the editor to make an accept/reject decision.  So you should be receiving that decision fairly soon.  The status "finished" does not suggest that a decision has been made, or say anything about what it is likely to be.

Comment: Stop checking the status of your paper. That is not productive. Instead put it out of mind and wait patiently for an email from the journal. (Exception: the process takes an unreasonably long time.)